# jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to add class to `<a>`, what has some url. For exampe :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;                    
    $(".navholder ul li a").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('sel');
    });

});
```

I want to add `"sel"` class to `<a>` what has `href=pathname`.

Theoretically something like this :

```
$(".navholder ul li a").attr('href', pathname).addClass('sel');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line:

`$(".navholder ul li a[href='"+ pathname +"']").addClass('sel');`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [jQuery selector syntax](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

```
$('.navholder ul li a [href=\\/foo\\/bar]').addClass('sel');
```

Note that you must escape `/` in jQuery expressions, and double-escape if it is a string literal.